# How to show that $\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} (t^2+1)^{-s} dt = \pi^{1/2} \frac{ \Gamma(s-1/2)}{\Gamma(s)}$

Tags: special-functions, improper-integrals

I want to compute the integral 
$$
\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} (t^2+1)^{-s} dt
$$
for $s \in \mathbb{C}$ such that the integral converges ($\mathrm{Re}(s) > 1/2$ I think) in terms of the Gamma function. If I'm not mistaken, the answer I'm looking for is

$$
\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} (t^2+1)^{-s} dt = \pi^{1/2} \frac{\Gamma(s-1/2)}{\Gamma(s)}
$$
so my question is how to prove the above formula?

**Motivation**

Since people sometimes ask for motivation, I'm reading a paper in which the author gives the evaluation of a certain Fourier coefficient but doesn't show the computations, just states the result. I was able to reduce the problem of checking the author's evaluation of the Fourier coefficient to proving the above formula for the integral.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $x=\dfrac1{t^2+1}$ and then recognize the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral.

But first, using the [parity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions) of the integrand, write $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)~dt~=~2\int_0^\infty f(t)~dt$.

Comment: Exactly, was just working this out. Make sure to use the evenness of your original integrand.

Comment: Thank you Lucian, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\pars{t^{2} + 1}^{-s}\,\dd t
     =\pi^{1/2}\,{\Gamma\pars{s - 1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{s}}}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#00f}{\large%
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\pars{t^{2} + 1}^{-s}\,\dd t}
> =\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{1 + t}^{-s}t^{-1/2}\,\dd t}
> ^{\ds{x \equiv {1 \over t + 1}\ \imp\ t = {1 \over x} - 1}}
> =
> \int_{1}^{0}x^{s}\pars{{1 \over x} - 1}^{-1/2}\,\pars{-\,{\dd x \over x^{2}}}
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{1}x^{s - 3/2}\pars{1 - x}^{-1/2}\,\dd x
> ={\Gamma\pars{s - 1/2}\Gamma\pars{1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{s}}
> =\color{#66f}{\large%
> \root{\pi}\,{\Gamma\pars{s - 1/2}\over \Gamma\pars{s}}}\,,
> \\[3mm]&\color{#c00000}{\large\Re\pars{s} > \half}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(t^2 + 1)^{-s}dt = 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}(t^2 + 1)^{-s}dt = 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sec^2u)^{1-s}du = 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2s-2}udu$

But,

$$
2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2m+1}\theta\sin^{2n+1}\theta d\theta = \dfrac{\Gamma(m+1)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(m+n+2)}
$$
Thus,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(t^2 + 1)^{-s}dt = 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2s-2}udu = \dfrac{\Gamma(s - 1/2)\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(s)} =\sqrt{\pi}\dfrac{\Gamma(s - 1/2)}{\Gamma(s)}
$$